# How do I take the female mean from the male mean?

Tags: r

I'm looking to find the difference between two means in R, so I can calculate effect size. I'm new to R, and working at a very basic level.
I'm analysing the gender pay gap from a glassdoor data set, and I want to calculate the difference between the male meanbasepay and female meanbasepay.
[code for calculating mean base pay by gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrSop.png)
[image]

Comment: This image would have looked better if posted as TEXT, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow. As Luuk mentions, a snippet of data as opposed to a screenshot would greatly improve your chance of a helpful reply. But how does this work for you?

```
df <- tibble(gender = c("Female", "Male"), 
             meanBasePay = c(90052.34, 98556.14),
             medBasePay = c(90426.0, 97862.5),
             cnt = c(463, 522))

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(!c(cnt, medBasePay), names_from = gender, values_from = meanBasePay) %>% 
  mutate(meanBaseDiff = Male - Female)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Female   Male meanBaseDiff
   <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
1 90052. 98556.        8504.
```

Another option is to use  the `lag` function. For example:

```
df %>%
  mutate(meanBaseDiff = meanBasePay - lag(meanBasePay))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  gender meanBasePay medBasePay   cnt meanBaseDiff
  <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Female      90052.     90426    463          NA 
2 Male        98556.     97862.   522        8504.
```